# how to tell webpack to serve public/index.html

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run `webpack-dev-server app/input.js public/output.js` and browse to `localhost:8080`, the browser shows the directory contents of my project folder instead of `public/index.html`.

How do I tell webpack-dev-server to serve `public/index.html`?

I am not using a configuration file yet, but will happily do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--content-base` flag like so:

```
webpack-dev-server app/input.js public/output.js --content-base public
```

See more information at http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base